# GDAL warp & GDAL contour inconsistent results

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, contour, gdal-contour

I am creating 2 output contours based on the same input DEM, one is clipped to a smaller grid feature (green line) while the other is clipped to a larger irregular polygon (blue line).

The problem is there is a .05m gap between the 2 results and the ends of the smaller feature have a bend to them, where the larger feature is straight.

I am using this code to generate the results where the `cutline_layer` is either the grid feature or large irregular polygon:

```py
    # clip the DEM from cutline layer
    dem = gdal.Warp(raster_out,
                    dem_file,
                    format='GTiff',
                    xRes=2,
                    yRes=2,
                    cutlineDSName=cutline_layer,
                    dstSRS='EPSG:3424',
                    cropToCutline=True)
    dem = None  # remove from memory

    # create the contour
    temp_shapefile_dir = os.path.join('temp', 'contour')
    out_shapefile = os.path.join(temp_shapefile_dir, f"{id_property}.shp")
    os.system(f'gdal_contour -a elevation -i 2 "{raster_out}" "{out_shapefile}"')
```

**Output**

- Blue line - Contour from large Irregular cutline
- Green line - Contour from smaller Grid cutline
- Gray dash - Cutline being used for smaller DEM (green line)

[image]

Comment: Is the pixel size of both DEMs the same 2x2 m? Have you tried to warp both extracts by using `-tap` parameter?

Comment: @user30184 yes the input DEM is the same file with 2x2 pixel size. The only difference is the cutline. I have not tried the `-tap` parameter but Ill give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Please do. By default gdalwarp makes the raster to match with the extents of data and you can probably see from gdalinfo reports that the origins of those two images are not aligned to full pixels.

Comment: @user30184 I tried the `-tap` parameter and that did not change the results. I updated the above image for clarity.

Comment: If the difference is about quarter of a pixel that does not feel so huge because contours are interpolated in any case. The bend is odd but without sample data it is difficult to say why it appears.